# How do I verify that my LINQ-to-SQL model matches the database schema?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am absolutely new to the .NET world, and started with C# on friday. I have some experience with database apps, though.

We will go with LINQ-to-SQL for a medium scale project. I am used to generating my schema from classes and keep track of changes with subversion and equivalents to Ruby's Migrations. There obviously is [no easy way to do this with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145/generating-database-tables-from-object-definitions) itself.

So I thought of generating the schema (and do some data access) with [Castle Project's ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) and use [Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) [Tarantino](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/wiki/DatabaseChangeManagement) or [dbdeploy.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdeploy-net/) for the schema updates. (Any suggestions for this?)

My main question is: **How do I verify that my LINQ classes still match the database schema? Does LINQ throw exceptions if the schema does not match? Can I iterate over all the LINQ classes and invoke some verify method?**

I already found that [sqlmetal is the way to regenerate the classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022/best-way-to-update-linq-to-sql-classes-after-database-schema-change).

PS: We will use SQL Server (2008 or 2005).

Answer (score 3):

This [tool](http://blog.huagati.com/res/index.php/2008/07/17/tools-part-2-add-ins-dbml-synchronization-add-in-updated/) will help sync them, but I'm unsure if it'll show differences...may be of some use though. (:

EDIT: As [KristoferA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11241/kristofera) said in his comment, it does support comparisons (: - thanks KristoferA.

Comment: It supports both update and compare. You can read more, download, and get a trial license at http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Comment: Thanks Kieron, I was hoping for some more answers. Pointing me to DBML Tools is great. Currently I am on Visual Studio Express, so I will probably have to switch to some Pro version to use the add-in.

Answer (score 2):

As for the:

> I am used to generating my schema
>   from classes and keep track of changes

I just added a DDL generation feature to [Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) (ver 1.47, released today). It can generate [DDL diff scripts](http://blog.huagati.com/res/index.php/2008/11/21/tools-part-6-add-ins-model-first-in-linq-to-sql-and-entity-framework/) in case you have added things to your Linq-to-SQL designer but not yet added them to the database.